# how to get rid of converting large numbers in excel sheet to exponential? Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

In the excel sheet , i have Salary columns with large numbers.

But when i read the excel file with read_xlsb() and display the dataframe,

that  columns are printed in scientific format with exponential.

How can get rid of this format?

Thanks

Output in R

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way I have found is to use to Notedpad++ to ensure the large numbers don't get cut or rounded off.

The way I do it

1. do not make any changes to the CSV file
2. Open it with Notedpad++, you will see the full number
3. save the notepad ++ file as txt
4. Open the txt file using excel

you will find that the number is no longer cut

Comment: Don't think that's the intended answer. OP wants the numbers in `R` to be displayed in non-scientific notation.